# Show icons in the dock contextual menus in OS X?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

My question is quite simple :

To use a custom menu for the apps icon on the dock, `- (NSMenu*) applicationDockMenu: (id) sender;` of the `NSApplicationDelegate` has to return the menu that the dock will display.

Using `setImage` on a `NSMenuItem`, you can normaly add icons to the menu. They show up on the normal menu, but not on in contextual menu of the app's dock icon.

Then how did Apple manage QuickTime, XCode, Preview to show icons in the list of recent opened files accessible in their dock contextual menu ?

Thx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The recent files list is actually part of the standard Dock icon menu. To use it in your app, you should build an `NSDocument`-based application. By using `NSDocument`, you will get the recent files menu/behaviour for free.

If your application cannot be based on `NSDocument`, you can instruct Cocoa to maintain a recent documents list based on URLs:

```
NSDocumentController *docController = [NSDocumentController sharedDocumentController];
[docController noteNewRecentDocumentURL:locationOfMyRecentFile1];
[docController noteNewRecentDocumentURL:locationOfMyRecentFile2];
[docController noteNewRecentDocumentURL:locationOfMyRecentFile3];
```

Note that currently, `-noteNewRecentDocumentURL:` only supports `file://` URLs (which you can create from a path with `+[NSURL fileURLWithPath:]`.) In the future, its behaviour will presumably change to allow URLs with other schemes.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my understanding, which is partly conjectural and related to implementation details:

The Dock runs in a separate process, and you can't pass an arbitrary `NSImage` trivially across the process boundary from your application to the Dock. There are only two kinds of images that can be passed properly: standard system icons, and icons in your resource bundle. But I don't think `NSImage` does the necessary incantations for either of these to work.

[So you're going to have to use Carbon.](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/customizing_docktile/tasks/docktasks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000986-CH5-TPXREF103) Specifically, you need to use `SetMenuItemIconHandle` with either `kMenuSystemIconSelectorType` (covers Carbon `IconRef`s, obtained with `GetIconRef`) or `kMenuIconResourceType` (`CFString`s that refer to an `.icns` file in your application bundle's Resources folder).

The relevant headers are `<HIToolbox/MacApplication.h>` (for `GetApplicationDockTileMenu`), `<HIToolbox/Menus.h>` (for `SetMenuItemIconHandle`) and `<HIServices/Icons.h>`, (for `GetIconRef`, if you're using system icons).

Untested, but it should look something like this:

```
#include <Carbon/Carbon.h>

SetMenuItemIconHandle(
    GetApplicationDockTileMenu(),
    [dockMenu indexOfItem:dockMenuItem],
    kMenuIconResourceType,
    (Handle) CFSTR("icon.icns")
);
```

It may not be this simple; some of this may be 32-bit only.

Comment: "Not available to 64-bit applications." :(

Comment: There must be something else, QuickTime, Preview & XCode are 64-bits apps.

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler Isn't that something that `NSDocumentController` does? It might use a private Apple API.

Comment: I don't know. Is it ? After looking it might be a private Apple API. I couldn't find a non-Apple app that has the icons. MS Office has nothing to ...

Comment: I note that BBEdit also displays a menu with recent files including icons, and also has other options e.g. show Scratchpad

Comment: Note that `BBEdit` shows that menu only when it is running. Which seems not a hard task to do according to this document: http://cocoadevcentral.com/articles/000036.php. `TextMate` keeps list of recent items when app is not running. But `TextMate` shows currently opened document indicator only while running. So, looks like `TextMate` uses menu made by `noteNewRecentDocumentURL` plus custom menu and menu items.