# Application Dock Menu with image on menu item

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, dock

Using `-(NSMenu *)applicationDockMenu:(NSApplication *)sender` I was able to create a right-click menu for my application dock icon, however I can't set an image to its menu items.

I've found some results related to that on Google, however they are from many years ago (Mac OS 10.2 and 10.3), and on that time that was unsupported. Someone knows if that's still unsupported or if there is some way to do it?

I also saw the recent documents suggestion in that answer, however, in my case, I can't use it; each menu item has its own action and they aren't related to specific files.

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/11418449/4370893

My app isn't in the App Store, so if the method include using some private API there is no problem.

**EDIT (July 31th, 2016):** Ok, I gave up and decided to use the recent documents area, however there is still a problem: a need to update the menu items constantly, and it seems that I cannot do that (at least not in `applicationDidFinishLaunching`, where it is suppose to happen firstly).

The following code didn't produced any change in the recent documents list:

```
NSDocumentController *docController = [NSDocumentController sharedDocumentController];
[docController clearRecentDocuments:nil];
for (int index = 0; index < items.count; index ++) {
    [docController noteNewRecentDocumentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[items[index] objectForKey:@"Path"]]];
}
```

Note: items is an NSArray of NSDictionary which always have the "Path" key, and yes, I've tested it and all of them are there; in fact if I use:

```
NSLog(@"%@",docController.recentDocumentURLs);
```

I can see the changes happening after each step, however these changes doesn't appear when I right click the Dock icon (my app not document based so I can't confirm if the same applies to the Open Recent menu since it's not there).

**EDIT 2 (July 31th, 2016):** I just found that thread with what seems to be the same problem I'm having. Was that solved?

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7328388?tstart=0

Comment: Which buttons? Do you mean menu item?

Comment: Yeah, just fixed that in my question.

Comment: Are you displaying documents in the dock menu? If not you can't have icons in the dock menu.

Comment: Nope, not displaying documents. It doesn't apply to my case. So there is absolutely no way to display icons in the menu items of the Dock menu?

Comment: In non-NSDocument based application you can call `NSDocumentController .noteNewRecentDocumentURL`. It will build system, non-customisable menu items in dock (aka `Recent documents`). Below this menu you can add custom menu items. By registering custom, customisable, dock menu `NSApplicationDelegate.applicationDockMenu`. In this custom menu you can show, for instance, list of application windows (like it did in TextMate.app).